# Java App Does Not Load Data from PostgreSQL

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

My Java app works fine locally, but now when I have deployed it on an EC2 instance (Ubuntu 14, Tomcat 8, PostgreSQL 9.3), I am getting the following error (see below). The back-end was written by another developer who is no longer part of the team. Basically, it needs to display some data once a value is chosen from a dropdown menu.

I've been Google-ing this issue like crazy but have found no solution. I was thinking it may be related to the `jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dbName`. I even tried inserting the actual IP instead of `localhost` but still no luck. To me, it seems like an issue with connecting with the database rather than with the code. As I mentioned, it is running fine locally on my computer.

Any guidance will be greatly appreciated as I am not a Java expert. Thanks for your help.

The full error log is below:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
com.app.data.ConnectionPool.freeConnection(ConnectionPool.java:52)
com.app.data.appDB.getData(appDB.java:155)
com.app.servlets.GetAppServlet.processRequest(GetAppServlet.java:42)
com.app.servlets.GetAppServlet.doGet(GetAppServlet.java:67)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:315)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: The Exception looks like a coding bug rather than a database connection problem. Show the ConnectionPool source code.

Comment: So what happens in `com.app.data.ConnectionPool.freeConnection` on line 52?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Line 52 states `connection.close();`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what little you have provided, my best guess is that the `connection.close()` method you mention is being called in a `finally` block where there isn't any check to see whether `connection` is `null`.

I imagine your code looks something like the following:

```
Connection connection = null;
try {
    connection = getDatabaseConnectionSomehow(...);
    // do stuff with database
}
finally {
    connectionPool.freeConnection(connection);
}
```

If the calll to `getDatabaseConnectionSomehow(...)` throws an exception, then `connection` will be `null` when the `finally` block is entered.  The code I presented above doesn't check to see whether `connection` is `null`, and if your `freeConnection` method also fails to check whether the connection is `null` before closing it, you will get a NullPointerException.

An exception thrown from within a `finally` block will replace any exception thrown within the corresponding `try` block.  So in your case, you don't see the real exception getting the database connection because the NullPointerException gets in the way.

Hopefully, adding a suitable null-check should help you figure out what the real problem is here.